# AngularJS: CSS doesn't appear to have any effect on HTML

Tags: html, css, angularjs, widget

I have an AngularJS app, and on one of the pages, I am displaying a number of widgets. The widgets all have a toolbar, which displays the name of the widget, and a number of buttons (different buttons depending on the widget).

The buttons on the widget toolbar are currently being displayed right next to each other:

[image: Widget navigation buttons]

I want to add some 'padding' to the toolbar, so that there is a bit of spacing between the buttons.

Bootstrap is already in use in the app for other aspects of the layout/ presentation of elements, so I want to use this to improve the layout of the buttons on the widget toolbar too.

I tried adding `padding` attributes to the panels on which the buttons are displayed in the CSS file:

```
.widget-preview .panel-heading .pull-right {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 5px; /* added this line to try and sort the spacing between buttons on widget heading */
  padding-right: 5px; /* added this line to try and sort the spacing between buttons on widget heading */
}

/* Overlaid edit panel on previewed widget */
.widget-preview-edit-panel {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  // Align with panel-heading height
  height: 38px;

  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;

  padding-right: 5px; /* added this line to try and sort the spacing between buttons on widget heading */
  padding-left: 5px; /* added this line to try and sort the spacing between buttons on widget heading */

  span {
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
}
```

and then set the `class` of the two images used in the directive.js template to the `class` defined in the CSS:

```
'<i data-ng-hide="hideChartPageBtn" class="pull-right glyphicon-clickable ti-bar-chart" data-ng-click="chartPage()" ></i>' +
'<i class="pull-right ti-home" data-ng-click="goHomePage()" ng-show="customhomepage"  /> ' +
```

But for some reason, this hasn't actually made a difference to how the images are displayed- there is no visible 'padding'/ space between them...

Why is this? How can I ensure that the CSS I've added is actually applied to these buttons?

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if you have added the padding correctly?

Comment: Just had a look, and the padding does not appear to be there for the buttons... When I inspect the buttons, the `.pull-right` section shows: `.pull-right{ float: right !important; }`, but doesn't show the padding anywhere... If I edit the `.pull-right` section in the console, to manually add the padding in, then I can see that this has the desired effect. So it seems I must be adding it to the wrong place in the CSS/ JS... how can I determine where I should add it?

Comment: In the console, the `.pull-right` style states that it is coming from bootstrap.css, line 8141- when I search for 'bootstrap' in my project folder, the only file it returns is 'bootstrap.scss, which only contains the one line: `@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";`, so it would seem that this CSS is coming from the bootstrap library- how can I manipulate this myself?

Comment: Do you have any custom css file?

Comment: Yes- `widgets.css`, which is where the block of CSS in my OP is from. There's a lot more in there than that, but that's the part I want to make changes to.

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` in your custom css file?

Comment: Just tried adding that to those elements, but it's not made any difference...